# UITableViewCell accessoryType won't be visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, tableview

The cell's accessory type won't display. I have tried both `cell.accessoryType` and `cell.accessoryView` (with an image). The table view works fine aside from this. Any suggestions? Thanks

**My code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.text = @"Hi";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Hi again!";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
```

Comment: I tried out your code. Everything works fine. I dont see any issues with your code. If you stillneed help show little more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table cell width fit into the screen. You are creating UITableView programmatically or it is in nib? If you are creating programmatically, check the frame size of table view also you can share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Choose accessory type from `xib` / `storyboard` of your `table view cell`.

[image]